# Does Gemini embedding model support languages other than English?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-cloud-ai, google-gemini

I am planning to use the Gemini embedding model (`models/embedding-001`) for document/query retrieval, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation if it support languages other than English. Specifically Greek.
I wonder if I can get an accurate embedding if my document and query are both in Greek and if my document is in Greek and my query is in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get embeddings for Greek, you can use vertexai's text embedding model [textembedding-gecko@001](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/embeddings/get-text-embeddings#language_coverage_for_textembedding-gecko-multilingual_models) which supports it.
Code example:

```
from vertexai.language_models import TextEmbeddingModel

def text_embedding() -> list:
    """Text embedding with a Large Language Model."""
    model = TextEmbeddingModel.from_pretrained("textembedding-gecko-multilingual@001")
    embeddings = model.get_embeddings(["What is life?"])
    for embedding in embeddings:
        vector = embedding.values
        print(f"Length of Embedding Vector: {len(vector)}")
    return vector
```

Comment: I think that for multilingual tasks the right model to use would be `textembedding-gecko-multilingual@001`. But your answer sent me in the right direction, hence I have accepted it. Thank you

Comment: @DarioB I updated the model name